# Showing a Database Details in Next Activity Using a ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I'm new in Android Studio,

I already have database file with 3 columns (ID, title, details)

I want to create a ListView contains 'title' from database and when I click one of the title, it will heading to next activity and show 'details' from the title I clicked before.

Database file is located in assets folder.

I'm using Android Studio latest version, please help me xml, java and manifest code. Thank you.

here are my code, i'm only success to show the 'title' column in the ListView, i don't know how to do the rest.

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String DBNAME = "story.db";
    static final String DBASSETPATH = "databases/" + DBNAME;
    static final String DBTABLE = "table";
    static final String DBTITLE = "title";
    static final String IDCOLUMN = "_id";

    ListView mTableList;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mCsr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTableList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.storylist);
        mDB = openStoryDB();
        if (mDB != null) {
            mCsr = mDB.query(DBTABLE,
                    new String[]{IDCOLUMN + " AS _id",
                            DBTITLE
                    },
                    null,null,null,null,null);
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCsr,
                    new String[]{DBTITLE},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
            mTableList.setAdapter(mSCA);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to open Database.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }


}

    private SQLiteDatabase openStoryDB() {
        String dbpath = this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).exists()) {
            Log.d("OPENSTORYDB","Opening already existing Database");
            return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        InputStream is;
        byte[] buffer;
        FileOutputStream db;
        try {
            is =  this.getAssets().open(DBASSETPATH);
            buffer = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OPENSTORYDB","Unable to locate or buffer input from assets " + DBASSETPATH);
            return null;
        }
        // Just in case the databases directory doesn't exist create it.
        File dbmkdir = (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME)).getParentFile();
        dbmkdir.mkdirs();
        try {
            db = new FileOutputStream(this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OPENSTORYDB","Unable to create outputstream for DB at path " + dbpath);
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        try {
            db.write(buffer);
            db.flush();
            db.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("OPENSTORYDB","Failed to copy asset to DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.book.story.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/storylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Fantomas : check my edited question

Comment: Consider using Room in conjunction with LiveData instead as per recommended by the official Android development guidelines, here is an example: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

1. add a ListView to the appropriate layout of the initial activity.
2. create a database helper class that will :

   1. Check to see if the database already exists
   2. If the database does not exist then copy the database from the assets folder
   3. provide methods to access the data as required (in the case of populating a Listview a method will be needed to retrieve the data to be listed)
3. in the initial activity obtain an instance of the database helper class
4. get the ListView via it's id.
5. instantiate a suitable adapter for the ListView.
6. set the ListView to use the adapter
7. Add the onItemClick Listener to the ListView which will extract sufficient details (the id) from the selected item, setting Intent extra(s) with the details and then start  the other activity (which can then extract the details from the Intent).

## Example

The following as an example based upon your question.

### The Database

The Database named **mydb** and as such is a file called **mydb** in the assets folders has the table **mytable** which conatins :-

[image]

### The Layout

A simple layout, includes a Listview that has been given an id of  has been used for the activity named **MainActivity**, the code for the ListView is :-

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

### The DatabaseHelper

The database helper has been created as **DBHelper.java**. When being instantiated it checks to see if the database exists as a file, if it doesn't then it attempts to copy the database from the assets folder (a runtime exception is thrown if it fails e.g. if the asset doesn't exist). The database is then opened. There is one public method **getAllFromMytable** that returns a Cursor with all rows from the mytable table :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb"; //<<<<<<<<<< Database file name including extension
    public static final int DBVERSION = 101;

    public static final String TBL_MYTABLE = "mytable"; //<<<<<<<<<< The table name
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_ID = "id"; //<<<<<<<<<< The id column name
    public static final String COl_MYTABLE_TITLE = "title"; //<<<<<<<<<< The title column name
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_DETAILS = "details"; //<<<<<<<<<< The details column name

    Context mContext;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mContext = context;

        if(!ifDBExists()) {
            copyDatabaseFromAssetsFolder();
        }
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    public Cursor getAllFromMytable() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"*, id AS " + BaseColumns._ID}; //<<<<<<<<<< need column named _id so generate it
        return  mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    private void copyDatabaseFromAssetsFolder() {

        int stage = 0, buffer_size = 4096, blocks_copied = 0, bytes_copied = 0;

        try {
            InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
            stage++;
            OutputStream os =  new FileOutputStream(mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME));
            stage++;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0) {
                blocks_copied++;
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                bytes_copied += length;
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String exception = "";

            switch (stage) {
                case 0:
                    exception = "Unable to open asset file " + DBNAME;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    exception = "Unable to open the Database file " + DBNAME + " for output.";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exception = "Error whilst copying " + DBNAME +
                            " from the assets folder to " + mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).toString() +
                            " - successfully copied " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks."
                    ;
            }
            throw  new RuntimeException(exception + " (see stack-trace above)");
        }
    }

    // Check if the Database exists
    private boolean ifDBExists() {
        File db = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME);
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        if (!db.getParentFile().exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity

This undertakes 4-7, except that rather than starting another activity the details of the clicked item in the ListView are displayed via a Toast :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mMyListView;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< Instantiate the DBHelper

        mMyListView = this.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    }

    private void manageListView() {
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getAllFromMytable(); //<<<<<<<<<< get the latest data from the database
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCsr,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_TITLE},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mMyListView.setAdapter(mSCA);
            mMyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    // Start the other activity here passing the id (sufficient to find the specififc row)via an intent extra

                    // Toast used as an example of extracting the respective data from the cursor
                    Toast.makeText(
                            mContext,
                            "You clicked on the row with an id of " + String.valueOf(id) +
                            " the Title is " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_TITLE)) +
                            " the Details are " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_DETAILS)) +
                            " the id column is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_ID))),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< ensure that the cursor is closed when done with
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView(); //<<<<<<<<<< refresh the listview
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- Please refer to comments and/or appropriate documentation that can easily be obtained via a search
- **ManageListView** is not called  directly as the **onResume** method runs when the activity is started.

## Result

A screen shot with the Toast :-

[image]

## Additional

Passing the id to another activity, then extracting the details column in that activity.

First, Add a new method to the database helper class to allow the details column to be returned as a string and obtained according to the **id**

e.g. the DBHelper.java above would have the following added :-

```
public String getDetailsFromId(long id) {
    String rv = "";
    String whereclause = COL_MYTABLE_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_MYTABLE_DETAILS));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

The create the other activity ensuring that it is defined in the manifest (using File/New/Activity amends the manifest accordingly).

This activity could be something like (this will display the details as per the id passed as a long via the intent extra used to start the activity) :-

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String INTENTKEY_MYTABLEIDCOLUMNS = "ikey_mytableidcolumn";

    TextView mDetails;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        mDetails = this.findViewById(R.id.mydetails);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        long id = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(INTENTKEY_MYTABLEIDCOLUMNS,-1);
        mDetails.setText(mDBHlpr.getDetailsFromId(id));

    }
}
```

Lastly amend the initial activity to instantiate an Intent that can be used to start the other activity, then put the id as an extra and finally start the other activity e.g. the following could be used in the above activity instead of (as well as if you wanted) the Toast :-

```
        mMyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Start the other activity here passing the id (sufficient to find the specififc row)via an intent extra

                // Toast used as an example of extracting the respective data from the cursor
                /*
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "You clicked on the row with an id of " + String.valueOf(id) +
                        " the Title is " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_TITLE)) +
                        " the Details are " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_DETAILS)) +
                        " the id column is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_MYTABLE_ID))),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                */

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,OtherActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(OtherActivity.INTENTKEY_MYTABLEIDCOLUMNS,id);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

The result (as per the other activity when an item is clicked (1st in this case)) :-

[image]

Comment: I edited my question with my code, thank you for your answer, but what I want, the 'details' column showed in other activity/layout, so how to make transtition between activity to show the 'details' from the selected 'title' in ListView', thank you

Comment: @Khamid Answer now includes example that displays the details in another activity obtained via the id being passed from the initial activity.

Comment: Oh, well! This is a great answer indeed.